# Real time animation of a hand

Tags: python, animation, game-engine

I want to animate a model of a human hand in Real-Time using bending sensors to measure the movement of the fingers. Currently I have a model of a hand as a mesh and rigged it with bones and parented the bones to the mesh. I also can move the different fingers using a python script and calling the owner.update() method.

My problem is that whenever I try to start my python script which reads the data from the USB interface and then rotates the corresponding finger Blender completely freezes. I can only unfreeze it by triggering an interrupt in the console window and then see the last position my hand has moved to. But the interesting part is that when I program the script to print to the console, the script itself seems to run without problems. It is just Blender freezing but the script working fine.

How do I get Blender to unfreeze and run my animation smoothly?
Can it be that my hand model is to complicated to render in realtime? It has around 2000 vertices and I don't know if this is much or not since I don't have much experiance with Blender.
Or do I have to run the script in another thread?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Robert

Comment: EDIT:
I found out that Blender freezes until the python script is finished. No matter what the program does, sleep for a few seconds or set the fingers to different positions, Blender freezes until the script is over and then displays the last position.

Comment: Sleeping may not work as expected either. Suggest using a modal timer operator (see _`text editor > templates > python > operator modal timer`_  )